# save and upload a file from internal memory

Tags: android, android-file

save and upload a file from internal  memory in android

**I had try to save a file into internal memory**

```
String smsXml = "<messages><sms><From>" + address + "</From><Date>" + finalDateString + "</Date><Body>" + msg +"</Body></sms></messages>";

            try {
                //saving the file as a xml
                FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("textMessage.xml",MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
                OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
                osw.write(smsXml);
                osw.flush();
                osw.close();
            }
            catch (Throwable e) {
                Log.d("Exception","Exception:"+ e);
            }
```

**Now I try to upload the file to server But how can I get file path to upload this.I had successfully uploaded a .mp3 from sd card but how to do that from internal memory.[Follow this link for uploading .mp3](http://wininterview.blogspot.in/2013/04/uploading-files-to-http-server-using.html)**

```
final String uploadFilePath = "android/data/data/com.example.sms/files/";
final String uploadFileName = "textMessage.xml";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [getFileStreamPath()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFileStreamPath%28java.lang.String%29). This will return the file created by `openFileOutput` method in `Files` directory.

```
File file = getFileStreamPath("textMessage.xml");
```

Then you can get the path String with [getPath](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#getPath%28%29) method:

```
String path = file.getPath();
```

Comment: that return a `File` not a `string`

Comment: Oh, yes. Then use getPath also.

Comment: there is no method named getPath

Comment: Are you sure? you will call it on File object. I have added the link to the method documentation. Check it.